# Yocto: Builhistory results

Tags: stm32, yocto

I am using Yocto for the first time and wanted to build an image for my STM32. In the end it says that the build was succesfull but I didn't understant the endnote after the build

```
NOTE: Fetching uninative binary shim http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/2.9/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.xz;sha256sum=d07916b95c419c81541a19c8ef0ed8cbd78ae18437ff28a4c8a60ef40518e423 (will check PREMIRRORS first)
Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03
Sstate summary: Wanted 988 Found 0 Missed 988 Current 0 (0% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2625 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 7 seconds
```

Why did it always miss (988) ?
Am I using the bitbake command in the wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sstate-cache is the mechanism used by Yocto to quicken rebuilds. It hashes tasks, recipes and variables when parsing and if a hash reappears some time later, the sstate-cache can be re-used and effectively bypasses this task/recipe by just using the previous run's output. When you build for the first time, you need to populate the sstate-cache and run all tasks of all dependencies, hence the "Missed 988" in the Sstate summary line. This is normal on a first run. If you change nothing and you still have misses after the first run, this should be investigated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer now I understand more. I will run the test again in the next days and see if the same message reappears.