# Yocto Build - Meaning of sstate summary

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to Yocto and building my first image for RaspberryPi. I've followed the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301562/yocto-builhistory-results). It seems to complete without errors but I am not sure if it is a successful build given the Sstate summary which says "Sstate summary: Wanted 173 Found 163 **Missed 1**" "**99% complete**". I repeatedly build the image but the results does not change.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301562/yocto-builhistory-results) but it does not seem to answer my questions.

I also understand that the shared state cache is used to rebuild only what is necessary.

My questions as follows:

1. does this mean that the build has completed or that something was missed and I'm not getting everything I asked for in the build recipe?
2. if something is missing, how do I go about finding out what was missed? I assume there is a log file?

Console output below:

```
Loading cache: 100% |######################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3588 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi4-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.13"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa72 crc crypto"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            = "dunfell:795339092f87672e4f68e4d3bc4cfd0e252d1831"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      = "dunfell:69f94af4d91215e7d4e225bab54bf3bcfee42f1c"
meta-raspberrypi     = "dunfell:934064a01903b2ba9a82be93b3f0efdb4543a0e8"
meta-rpi64           = "dunfell:c3a83d373eac2a4cd7f15894d0e33f0a2af47f56"
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-perl            = "dunfell:69f94af4d91215e7d4e225bab54bf3bcfee42f1c"
meta-qt5             = "dunfell:b4d24d70aca75791902df5cd59a4f4a54aa4a125"
meta-security        = "dunfell:b76698c788cb8ca632077a972031899ef15025d6"
meta-jumpnow         = "dunfell:b3995636741be0d219a50035c98ded8b48590888"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04
Sstate summary: Wanted 165 Found 164 **Missed 1** Current 1313 (99% match, **99% complete**)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4213 tasks of which 4209 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared state is a caching mechanism used by bitbake. The "Missed 1" means that one sstate task in the build couldn't be obtained from the sstate cache. This is perfectly fine, it just means it required to run that task and couldn't get it from the cache.

Comment: Thank you for providing the clarity Richard. Much appreciated!